Spring Boot Error: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type 'Utilisateur'
enter image description hereI'm working on a Spring Boot application and I'm encountering an issue with my JPA entity configuration. The application fails to start and throws the following error:
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type 'com.example.PORTClaimApp.Entity.Utilisateur'


Here are my entity classes:
"Utilisateur"
 package com.example.PORTClaimApp.Entity;

import com.example.PORTClaimApp.Enums.RoleUtilisateur;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Utilisateur {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idUtilisateur;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nom;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String prenom;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String motDePasse;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RoleUtilisateur role; //Client, Agent, Admin
    }



"Ticket"
package com.example.PORTClaimApp.Entity;

import com.example.PORTClaimApp.Enums.NiveauUrgence;
import com.example.PORTClaimApp.Enums.StatutTicket;
import com.example.PORTClaimApp.Enums.TypeTicket;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.Date;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Ticket {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idTicket;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TypeTicket type;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "theme_id")
    private Theme theme;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sousTheme_id")
    private SousTheme sousTheme;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private NiveauUrgence niveauUrgence;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String objet;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 1000)
    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StatutTicket statutTicket;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateOuverture;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateResolution;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateFermeture;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_client")
    private Utilisateur utilisateurClient;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_agent", nullable = true)
    private Utilisateur utilisateurAgent;
}

"Message"
package com.example.PORTClaimApp.Entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.Date;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idMessage;

    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String Contenu;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date DateHorloge;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_ticket")
    private Ticket ticket;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_emetteur")
    private Utilisateur emetteur;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_destinataire")
    private Utilisateur destinataire;
}

I've tried to ensure that all relationships are correctly defined and annotated. What might be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

it'll be great if you can provide your schema details

Thanks for your comment , i'v added my schema diagramm

As far as I know, this issue has many causes.
But you can try the following ways to see if it works. Make sure that your @Entity classes are loaded by @ComponentScan (or the package is underlying your main class)

Implement Serializable for each @Entity class
Add referenceColumnName to your @JoinColumn annotations, the value is the actual primary key names in each tables, ex: idUtilisateur.
Config bi-directional mapping, ex: @OneToMany(mappedBy="destinataire", insertable = false, updatable = false)

Hope this can fix your issue, or if there's another exception thrown, just let me know.

Thank you for your response. However, I believe the issue stems from my "Message" table having two foreign keys that reference the same "idUtilisateur" in the "Utilisateur" table. I set it up this way to store both the sender and receiver, who are both recorded in the "Utilisateur" table. I am unsure if there is a way to correctly implement this.

Try to to add annotations for the other side of bidirectional relationships, maybe it can solve your problem.
You can update Your Utilisateur entity to add these lines:
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "utilisateurClient")
private List<Ticket> ticketsClient;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "utilisateurAgent")
private List<Ticket> ticketsAgent;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "emetteur")
private List<Message> messagesEnvoyes;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "destinataire")
private List<Message> messagesRecus;

